# Git repo not accepting pushes after setup

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have created and initialized a git repo on a new turnkey version control server, and have added the remote with SSH.  Seem to have followed all the correct steps setting up a new repo, too.  I see it in the git web admin right next to helloworld repo.  Below is the addition of the remote server, followed by my failed attempt to push.

```
git remote add origin ssh://root@xxx.xx.xx.xx/git/projectName

git push origin master

fatal: "/git/project" does not appear to be a git repository

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can interact with the helloworld project just fine, but I did notice it seems to have permissions set up that my manually set up project does not.  Does this mean my repo is not completely set up?

Comment: @edhedges Nothign useful in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url you are using is not correct. It can't find a git repository at that place.

In case you created a bare repository, you need to add .git to it (git creates a directory called .git.

```
git remote add origin ssh://root@xxx.xx.xx.xx/git/projectName.git
```

Comment: Ahhh okay, in my helloworld example it used this line to make it publicly visible:

`ln -s /srv/repos/git/project.git project`

And so anytime I saw it I just saw the name as 'project' not 'project.git'.  I knew I was missing something stupidly simple.  Thank you.